# C++ Why Traits are not available on objects but rather are available as static member variables

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

My understanding about class Traits is that it is a class that encapsulates a set of types and functions necessary for template classes and template functions to manipulate objects of types for which they are instantiated.

In below example why we cannot make use of 'gquiz::container_type' declaration else how would we know the traits of gquiz :

```
int main()
{
    queue <int> gquiz;
    const queue <int>::container_type dq;
    //why not gquiz::container_type ?????
    cout << typeid(dq).name() << endl;
    gquiz.push(10);
    gquiz.push(queue <int>::value_type(20));
    gquiz.push(30);
}
```

Comment: `decltype(gquiz)::container_type` would be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
decltype(gquiz)::container_type
```

Indeed having `x::y` to be meant equivalent as `decltype(x)::y` when `x` is not a type would seem simpler and is something that I also (and I bet a lot others) thought about too. However it's not in the standard and the reason is that ... because it's not in the standard, so doesn't work.

Not every decision in C++ has logical grounds, may be this specific one has a logical reason but I cannot think to one.

May be there's just no reason.

With C++ happens. A lot.

Comment: It _does_ introduce even more ambiguity.

Comment: @chris: `x::y` when `x` is not a type is not legal code and even in templates basically the only thing you must tell the compiler about a generic `x` is if it's a type or a value. In which case `x::y` could mean something else when `x` is not a type and therefore considering it to mean `decltype(x)::y` could introduce ambiguity?

Comment: What I meant was ambiguity in things `identifier :: identifier` can mean, which of course is already more than one thing. More parsing (whether that be from computer or human) cases to handle.